# Can Necromactic Scroll and Papyrus Scarab be used at the same time?

Tags: terraria

I am trying to get as many summons as possible, and I am currently using the Papyrus Scarab. If I find another Necromactic Scroll, will I be able to equip it with the Papyrus Scarab?

I am asking because the Papayrus Scarab is made from the Necromactic Scroll, and I won't be able to get another Necro Scroll soon, so I want to see if its worth it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes

I haven't tested it myself, but according to the Wiki entry for the [Papyrus Scarab](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Papyrus_Scarab):

> This accessory stacks with the [Necromantic Scroll](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Necromantic_Scroll), allowing an additional increase in minion capacity.

The page on [Summon Weapons](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Summon_weapons) also states that the maximum amount of minions a character can have at one time is 11, with both the Papyrus Scarab and the Necromantic Scroll being listed as items to equip together to gain the desired effect.

Comment: I tested it after reading this (drop tables were in my favor) and I can confirm this.